# f.read I/O differences

Tags: python, linux, io

I am looking to optimize the size of a read operation for a file that is too big to open entirely  in memory. Here is a code sample:

```
def read_chars(fp, BSIZE=1024):
    with open(fp) as source:
        size=f.seek(0,2); f.seek(0)
        t0 = time.time()
        chars = True
        while chars:
            chars = source.read(BSIZE)
            for char in chars:
                pass # placeholder
        print ('Read %s in %.2fs' % (size, time.time() - t0))
```

The performance is directly related to the size of the buffer size I use, at least for relatively small buffer sizes. For example:

```
>>> read2('/Users/david/Desktop/Sales1M.csv', 1024)
Read 46468331 in 0.75s
>>> read2('/Users/david/Desktop/Sales1M.csv', 10)
Read 46468331 in 1.86s
>>> read2('/Users/david/Desktop/Sales1M.csv', 2)
Read 46468331 in 5.93s
```

What accounts for the huge difference in these numbers? At first I thought that the times would be almost the same, but perhaps the difference is related to the quantity of system file operations(?), but would like someone to give a more definitive answer to why the behavior is as it is.

Comment: _At first I thought that the times would be almost the same_ Why is that?

Comment: The argument to `f.read` isn't a buffer size; it's just the number of bytes to return from the file objects *internal buffer*. The increase in time you are seeing is entirely due to the number of function calls you make.

Comment: You are surprised that having to make 500 times more calls would take in the neighborhood of 500 times longer?

Comment: Could it be due to page size? Though the function is reading 2 bytes, however, it may be loading the bytes equal to the size of the page. Hence, 1024 could be faster because it doesn't have to load the same page again and again. But in case of 2 bytes that could be the case. I may be wrong. It may hold true when seek and read loads a fresh page again and again.

Comment: @ScottHunter could you please clarify? For example, there are 100x more calls between 10 and 1024 and it's only a 2x time difference.